# how can retrieve a string saved in the database correctly using a AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, jquery

This is the string saved in the database:

```
~`@#$%^&*()_+}{":?><,./;'[]=-|\"
```

But it returns as:

```
~`@#$%^&amp;*()_+}{&quot;:?&gt;&lt;,./;&#039;[]=-|\&quot;
```

This is my AJAX function:

```
function getComment(timesheetId,activityId,date,employeeId){

var r = $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        // contentType: " charset=utf-8",
        url: linkToGetComment,
        data: "timesheetId="+timesheetId+"&activityId="+activityId+"&date="+date+"&employeeId="+employeeId,
        async: false,

        success: function(comment){
            cmnt= comment;

        }
    });
    return cmnt;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling:

```
unescape(YOUR_STRING);
```

The special characters are being html encoded at some point, so you need to unencode them.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_unescape.asp

Answer (score 0):

Before un-escaping any string, you should really make sure your text is coming from a safe source and is not based on any user input.

That said, the unescape() function should work for you:

```
cmnt= unescape(comment);
```